# Setting app a full api service with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to create a small api using AWS that:

1. Enable users to register and get an API key
2. Enable users to send requests to save their data in DB like

> mysite.com/userApiKey/subject=name/data=22/data2=me

Where each user creates his own table or multiple tables with data.

I am looking for simple way to achive this especially with managing users keys.

I found that **AWS API GATEWAY** has some guide which i am not sure if it achive this:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-4/

It’s not exactly what i need . Is there a simple way setting it up fast so i can build my api? Any guide? GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Purpose of AWS API GATEWAY is to publish, maintain, monitor and secure APIs. You need to create API to achieve your business logic using back-end services such as application running in EC2 or code running from AWS LAMBDA.

[Serverless API using Lamda](https://blog.sicara.com/deploy-serverless-rest-api-lambda-s3-aws-2cf99b8f34ae) might help you to create api using AWS lambda